# When a test suite defined in an xml is executed, is it possible to assume that all tests in the suite is executed in the same JVM?

Tags: java, testng

I have a TestNG test suite defined in an xml file. This suite has a suite listener installed.

```
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.my.package.MyListener"/>
</listeners>
```

In `onStart()` of the suite listener, I initialize some static class members.

Is it guaranteed that all the test cases later executed in the suite are executed in the same JVM in which `onStart()` is fired, so that the static variable values I initialized in `onStart()` are available to all test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true, the same JVM will be used and therefore the same static fields will be available to all classes.

Nevertheless, I have found that there may be some initialization issues when the test suite is configured to run with multiple parallel threads (e.g. `thread-count="5" parallel="tests"`).

The issues did not reoccur after I added synchronization to the `onStart` method of my listener class:

```
public synchronized void onStart(ISuite suite) {
    // Initialization code
}
```